# Is there any way to pass a value from Vue js component to blade template

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade, vue-server-renderer

I am using ServerTable to render a list of companies and I want to take the total amount of records and show it in the blade template. Is there any way to pass the data from Vue component and show it in blade?

This is inside the Vue component:
`{{ items.count + 'results found' }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meaning laravels blade template engine - it's not possible. Blade runs on backend and vue runs on frontend.
What you should do is find how vuejs get `{{ items.count }}` (getting by ajax or directly on page from backend) and make blade use such method too

Comment: thank you for answering and yeah that's what i understand, since it's not possible i need to add the Html code from blade inside the component and show the value there, i think it's the best way to do it